# Trim whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I am aware of the trim() function for String and i am trying to implement it in my own to better understand regex. The following code does not seem to work in Java. any input ?

```
private static String secondWay(String input) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s+(.*)(\\s$)+");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
  String output = null;
  while(matcher.find()) {
    output = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println("'"+output+"'");
}
return output;
}
```

The output for

```
input = "    This is a test    " is 'This is a test   '
```

I am able to do it using an alternative way like

```
private static final String start_spaces = "^(\\s)+";
private static final String end_spaces = "(\\s)+$";
private static String oneWay(String input) {
       String output;
       input = input.replaceAll(start_spaces,"");
       output = input.replaceAll(end_spaces,"");
       System.out.println("'"+output+"'");
       return output;
}
```

The output is accurate as

```
'This is a test'
```

I want to modify my first method to run correctly and return the result.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect, it matches the beginning whitespace, your input (`greedy`) matching until the last whitespace and then it captures the last whitespace at the end of the string.

You want the following instead, following `.*` with `?` as well for a *non-greedy* match.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s+(.*?)\\s+$");
```

Regular expression:

```
^              # the beginning of the string
\s+            # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
(              # group and capture to \1:
 .*?           # any character except \n (0 or more times)
)              # end of \1
\s+            # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
$              # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

See [Demo](http://ideone.com/8foMl0)

EDIT: If you want to capture the leading and trailing whitespace into groups, just place a capturing group `()` around them as well.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\s+)(.*?)(\\s+)$");
```

- Group `1` contains leading whitespace
- Group `2` contains your matched text
- Group `3` contains trailing whitespace

FYI, for replacing the leading/trailing whitespace you can achieve this in one line.

```
input.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
```

Comment: I will accept your answer, but can you tell me how can i add the leading and trailing spaces into groups ?

Comment: Thank you @hwnd. ? was the missing link. :)

Comment: @AdilF following `.*` with `?` allows it to match the least amount possible, where `.*` matches the most amount possible.

Comment: I dont get it. With .* i got 'This is a test   '( with spaces. comments is removing the trailing spaces) while with .*? i get 'This is a test'. i am under the impression ? is making the group more greedy.

Comment: @AdilF Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3):

I realize you are using a `Pattern` and `Matcher`, but this is the easiest way to do it:

```
private static String secondWay(String input) {
    String pattern = "^\\s+|\\s+$"; // notice it's a string
    return input.replaceAll(pattern, ""); 
}
```

The regex is `^\\s+|\\s+$` which matches:

- all *starting* whitespace (`^` means start and `\\s+` means whitespace)
- *or* (`|` means or)
- all ending whitespace (`$` means end of line)

Comment: [ bangs head on the wall ] --> myself... Thank you.

Comment: @AdilF, its knowledge of implementing regular expression =)